# jQuery Validation on click without submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am using this amazing script for validating my form and for the normal functionality it works great, but I would like to validate the form on a onClick (a href) event instead on the submit (input).. is that possible?

Script:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

It must be something like this, right?

```
<a href="#" onClick="validate()" >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the [valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method on the form to see whether it is valid.

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('myformselecto').valid()" >
```

I would recommend adding the handler using jQuery rather than inlining it

Comment: This works great, thank you. I made it using jquery: $('#divid').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('form').valid(); });, but is it also possible to go to a div (#divid2) when valid?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery validation plugin hooks to the `submit` event of the form. Therefore all you need to do is make the click of that `a` element submit the form. Try this:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myForm').submit(); // this will then call the validate() func
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But I don't want to submit the form yet, that has to be done later on the page, I first want to validate and use a input submit to submit the form later on :)

Comment: Ah ok, no problem. Arun has the answer for you then :) But like he says, don't use the `onclick` attribute - attach your events in jQuery itself.