# trigger on click or href after validation

Tags: jquery, validation, swipe

I am having an form in a swipe slider, and I am using the following script to check if my form is valid without a submit because I want to input submit it in another slide:

```
$('#divId').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('form').valid(); });
```

That works great but now I would like to trigger the swipe onClick event only if the validation is correct:

```
<a href="#" onClick="mySwiper.swipeTo(1, 10)">
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?
*If valid(); = ok THEN onClick="mySwiper.swipeTo(1, 10)*

**Scripts:**
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

**Other Stack:**
[jQuery Validation on click without submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063772/jquery-validation-on-click-without-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the return value of `valid()` and put this in an 'if` statement.

```
$('#divId').click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   if ($('form').valid()){
     mySwiper.swipeTo(1, 10);
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try like this:

```
$('#divId').click(function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     $('form').valid(); 

     // your validation check goes here
     if( vadiation_pass ) {
         $('#link').attr("onClick", "mySwiper.swipeTo(1, 10)");
     } else {
         $('#link').removeAttr('onClick');
     }
});

// HTML
<a href="#" id="link">
```